# OCaml Type Inference, a concrete example

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I am reading Ocaml notes that have the example below:

```
let o f g x = (f (g (x)));;
val o : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>
```

There are no explanations from the notes about the type inference. In my understanding,  `('a -> 'b)` corresponds to `g(x)` and `('c -> 'a)` corresponds to `f()`. Am I correct? In addition, `'b` corresponds to the output of the entire function. What does 'c corresponds to? It would be appreciated if there is a full explanation about this type inference.

Comment: OCaml functions are curried. `t -> u -> v` is understood as `t -> (u -> v)` and is the type of a function which takes a `t` and (returns a functions which takes) a `u` and returns a `v`. So in your example, `('a -> 'b)` is the type of `f` (the 1st arg); `('c -> 'a)` is the type of `g` (the 2nd arg); `'c` is the type of `x` (the 3rd arg); and `'b` is the return type.

Comment: @Joe what are the “OCaml notes” you are reading? In which context are you reading them (for leisure, a faculty course about OCaml, or typing, or programming, etc.)? Your question is basic OCaml (no offense) so, depending on your context and intent, perhaps you should simply read an OCaml tutorial for beginners? Of course if it is already what you are doing, and you feel there are explanations missing, you can probably report it to the authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a few less parentheses:

```ml
let o f g x = f (g x);;
val o : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>
```

Function `g` takes a value of type `'a` and returns `'b`. We can therefore infer that `f` takes a value of type `'b` and returns `'c`.

But, because of the way the arguments run, we'll say `f` is of type `'a -> 'b` and `g` is of type `'c -> 'a` because the input type is unknown but it has to feed into `g` which takes `'a`.

Argument `x` gets sent to `g`, which expects a value of type `'c` so `x` is inferred to be of type `'c`. Since `f` has a return type of `'b`, the return type for the whole thing is `'b`.

Putting that all together, `o` has a type of `('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b`.

Perhaps a visual will help:

```
       +-----+     +-----+
(x)    |     |     |     |
'c -> 'c  g 'a -> 'a  f 'b -> 'b
       |     |     |     |
       +-----+     +-----+
```

Rearranging these to the order they appear in the definition of `o`:

```
  +-----+     +-----+
  |     |     |     |    (x)
 'a  f 'b    'c  g 'a    'c
  |     |     |     |
  +-----+     +-----+
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations and pattern draws. Especially the pattern helps a lot! I have a question, does ocaml read from left to right? For example, in this case, does ocaml read f first, then g, then x?

Comment: For the sake of assigning type annotations, it's left to right. In terms of evaluation, `g x` is evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding, ('a -> 'b) corresponds to g(x) and ('c -> 'a) corresponds to f().

You're backwards here -- `('a -> 'b)` is the type of the first (curried) argument to o -- f in this case.  `(c' -> a')` is the type of g, the second curried argument.

> 'b corresponds to the output of the entire function. What does 'c corresponds to?

`'c` is the type of x, the third argument.

So `o` takes three arguments (two functions and a value), passes the 3rd argument to the second (function) argument, passes the return value of that to the (first) function argument, and returns the result.  Exactly as decribed in the first line.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Yes, by following your answers, I figured out that the there is a correlation between arguments and types, hence, the type inference order should also corresponds to the order of arguments. In addition, since f and g are functions, they have input type and returned type inside of the brackets. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe, you have two answers. If they've helped you, you should accept one or both of them **A)** to give the authors due credit for their work, and **B)** to let other SO users know that this question has accepted answers.