# Understanding relation between let and val in interactive mode

Tags: ocaml

```ml
let app = fun f -> fun x -> f (x);;
(*val app : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>*)

let app = fun f -> fun x -> x (f+1);;
(*val app : int -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>*)

let app = fun f -> fun x -> x (f);;
(*val app : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>*)

let app2 = fun f -> fun g -> fun x -> g ( f x );;
(*val app2 : ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>*)

let app2 = fun f -> fun g -> fun x -> f (g x );;
(*val app2 : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>*)

let app2 = fun f -> fun g -> fun x -> g (f x+1);;
(*val app2 : ('a -> int) -> (int -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>*)

let app2 = fun f -> fun g -> fun x -> f (g x+1 );;
(*val app2 : (int -> 'a) -> ('b -> int) -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>*)

let app3 = fun f -> fun g -> fun x -> g f x+1 ;;
(*val app3 : 'a -> ('a -> 'b -> int) -> 'b -> int = <fun>*)
```

How do I know what happens in the `val` line without tapping enter on the `let app` line.
To be more specific I dont understand the relation between `let` and `val`.

For example, for the first one:

```
let app = fun f -> fun x -> f (x);;
(*val app : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>*)
```

What I see is that the first `x` takes the name `'a`
and after it goes to the `f` which takes the name `'b`
and after it goes to the fun `x` which is `'a` again
and after it goes to the fun `y` which is `'b` again.

But it is clearly not the case with other functions.
How do I know how they are related?

Comment: I highly recommend reading the first chapter of the OCaml manual: https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/htmlman/coreexamples.html , and this section: https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/htmlman/expr.html#sss:expr-function-definition . They will give you a really good grounding in the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has put the types of these functions in comments below the actual code. Comments in OCaml are surrounded by `(*` and `*)`.

These type signatures are identical to what you'd see in an OCaml toplevel. You enter an expression, followed by `;;`, this code is evaluated, and you're shown the resulting value.

Consider:

```ml
# 4 + 5;;
- : int = 9
# let a = 4 + 5;;
val a : int = 9
#
```

The `val` only shows up if I've introduced a *name* for the value. In either case we're shown the type of the resulting value and the value itself.

When you see things like `'a` and `'b` you're seeing type variables that OCaml *infers* when it can't infer a specific type. [This *very* recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289003/ocaml-type-inference-a-concrete-example) is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

`let` is used to create name-bindings(alternatively named definitions if you would like to call it), where a binding will have a name and will be bound to an expression, which when evaluated will produce a value.

`fun` is used to create/define anonymous function, Anonymous functions are `function expression` which means an expression of type function, which when evaluated given its arguments will produce a value, and this function expression can itself be passed around like any other regular value.. and this function expression is bound using a `let`.

For example

```
let app = fun f -> fun x -> x (f+1)
```

In this case, we are defining a name `app` which will be bound to the expression produced by `fun` on the right. The `fun` takes a parameter `f` whose type will be inferred by the compiler once it is done processing the body of that `function expression`. The same applies to the next `function expression` which takes a parameter named `x`.

By looking at the right-most expression, which is responsible for generating the reduced value, we see `f` getting applied to the operator `+` and so `f` will receive it's type from that expression. And then `x (...)` entails a `function application`, so the `x` will receive it's type from that expression.

And we can go on applying the same to every expression cited in the question.

Essentially, `let bindings`, `lambda expressions`, `type inference`, `function application`, `function expression` etc... are some of the topics one should get acquainted with to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Very helpful

Comment: @BesartNuha if you found this answer helpful, it is proper SO etiquette to accept any answers you find answer your question.